# Правильно ли расставлены знаки?

Tags: пунктуация

"Единственное, что им сейчас движет, — это желание убить" — правильно ли тут расставлены знаки препинания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая пунктуация возможна.

Comment: Думаю, что такая пунктуация здесь не только возможна, но и единственно верная

Comment: Я не уверен в абсолютной необходимости тире.  
Ну и опять - стык тире и запятой, на мой взляд это весьма спорный момент.

Comment: Нормально. Касательно запятой и тире - смотрите ruscorpora.

Comment: Что конкретно там смотреть? мы ж тут договориться не модем, а вы опять - пальцем в интернет.